# Overriding sharepoint list events

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss

I need to add custom handling to a lists' adding event. However, the event does not appear to be firing. I would like my custom handler defined in EventReceivers to fire anytime a new item of the custom type is added to the list.
I would appreciate any suggestions.
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace MyTestGroupListFeature
{
    class MyTestGroupListFeature : SPFeatureReceiver
    {
        private const string LISTNAME = "Acquisition Groups";
        private const string CONTENTTYPE_LISTNAME = "Contenttype List";
        private const string FOO = "FOO";
        private const string SITE_TEMPLATE_EXTENSION = ".stp";
    public override void FeatureInstalled
      (SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
    }

    public override void FeatureUninstalling
       (SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        FeatureDeactivating(properties);
    }

    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
            SPList list = GetList(web, LISTNAME);
            SPSite site = web.Site;
            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            SPContentType newCType = CreateSourceSystemContentType(web);
            SPList listct = web.Lists[CONTENTTYPE_LISTNAME];
            AddEventReceiverToList(listct);
            AddContentTypeToList(web, listct, newCType);
        }
        catch       {  }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a content type for Source System
    /// </summary>
    private SPContentType CreateSourceSystemContentType(SPWeb site)
    {
        //Create site columns
        string acronymFieldName = site.Fields.Add("Acronym", SPFieldType.Text, true);
        SPFieldText acronymField = (SPFieldText)site.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(acronymFieldName);
        acronymField.Group = "AQSIDM Columns";
        acronymField.Update();
        string nameFieldName = site.Fields.Add("Name", SPFieldType.Text, true);
        SPFieldText nameField = (SPFieldText)site.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(nameFieldName);
        acronymField.Group = "AQSIDM Columns";
        acronymField.Update();
        string descriptionFieldName = site.Fields.Add("Description", SPFieldType.Text, true);
        SPFieldText descriptionField = (SPFieldText)site.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(descriptionFieldName);
        descriptionField.Group = "AQSIDM Columns";
        descriptionField.Update();
        // Get the parent content type. 
        SPContentTypeId itemCTID = new SPContentTypeId("0x01");
        SPContentType itemCT = site.AvailableContentTypes[itemCTID];
        //Create SourceSystem content type:
        SPContentType sourceSystemCT = new SPContentType(itemCT, site.ContentTypes, "Source System");
        sourceSystemCT.Group = "Source System Content Types";

        //Add columns to content type
        sourceSystemCT = site.ContentTypes[sourceSystemCT.Id];
        SPFieldLink acronymLink = new SPFieldLink(acronymField);
        sourceSystemCT.FieldLinks.Add(acronymLink);
        //
        SPFieldLink nameLink = new SPFieldLink(nameField);
        sourceSystemCT.FieldLinks.Add(nameLink);
        //
        SPFieldLink descriptionLink = new SPFieldLink(descriptionField);
        sourceSystemCT.FieldLinks.Add(descriptionLink);
        //
        //sourceSystemCT.Update();
        string assemblyName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName;
        string ctReceiverName = "MyTestGroupListFeature.EventReceivers";
        sourceSystemCT.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdding, assemblyName, ctReceiverName);
        sourceSystemCT.Update(true);
        site.ContentTypes.Add(sourceSystemCT);
        return sourceSystemCT;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a custom content type to site's list
    /// </summary>
    private void AddContentTypeToList(SPWeb web, SPList list, SPContentType ct)
    {
        list.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
        list.ContentTypes.Add(ct);
        list.Update();
        // Add the item:
        SPListItem newItem = list.Items.Add();
        newItem["Acronym"] = "Acronym Field Added";
        newItem.Update();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Programmatically add new event receivers
    /// </summary>
    private void AddEventReceiverToList(SPList list)
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        SPEventReceiverDefinition eventReceiver = list.EventReceivers.Add();
        eventReceiver.Name = "On Updating";
        eventReceiver.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdding;
        eventReceiver.SequenceNumber = 200;
        eventReceiver.Assembly = assembly.FullName;
        eventReceiver.Class = "MyTestGroupListFeature.EventReceivers";
        eventReceiver.Update();
    }


}

class EventReceivers : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Test behavior when adding an item
    /// </summary>
    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdding(properties);
        SourceSystem ss = new SourceSystem();
        ss.Name = "sharepointss";
        ss.Acronym = "sharepoint acronym";
        ss.Description = "desc";
        ss.EndPoint = new Uri(@"\testURI");
        ss.Update("foo");
        ss.Create(String.Format("SourceSystem_Create_SP_{0:o}", DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you activated the feature, did you verify whether or not the event receiver was attached to the list? This can be done programatically or using tools such as SharePoint Manager.